# Can VSCode display a Markdown syntax preview pane?

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

I am typing a README document in Markdown using Visual Studio Code. I found an online browser-based  tool called [Markdown Live Preview](http://markdownlivepreview.com/), but I was wondering if VSCode had any sort of handy split-window pane already built into it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure that your document is saved as a Markdown file in VSCode:

File > Save as > README.md (The text will be color-coded.)

In the top right corner of VSCode, click the "Split Editor" icon to enable side-by-side editing.

Click the "Open Preview" magnifying glass icon to view a live preview of your Markdown syntax that updates as you type!

[image: VSCode Icon Labels]

Answer (score 9):

The *"Mouse-Clicks" way* seems inefficient, try *vscode pre-defined keybind* as `markdown.showPreviewToSide`:

```
ctrl+k v
```

which means when you are editing a markdown file, press `Ctrl+k`, then loosen both and press `v`, it comes a preview of current markdown file in the other splited side.

Answer (score 2):

Another command that can be used is "Markdown: Open Preview" which can be called both from intellisence (`ctrl + shift + p`, start typing "Markdown" to see available commands) or by a direct keybinding: default is `ctrl + shift + v`, custom may be set at Keyboard Shortcuts (`ctrl + k ctrl + s`).

However, this command opens the preview in another tab, so if you need splitted window, you'll need to do it manually or by some other hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to point out an alternate way of working with Markdown in vscode. The extension "Instant Markdown" will launch a local browser preview on :1090 (I believe) that allows you to position the render wherever you like. This is a pleasant way of watching the document grow in real time in a format that is much more like what you would see on Github for example. The preview pane in VSCode is a bit too dissimilar to the real thing for my taste.